# What is entropy in the concept of arrow of time?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, time, arrow-of-time

When I first started to study arrow of time, I first heard the word **Entropy** and after watching and reading internet resources I can't get what is this in the concept of **arrow of time**. So, please tell me what exactly it is to understand the concept of **arrow of time**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entropy as an arrow of time](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79256/)

Comment: This is the answer but it's difficult for me to understand as it introduces some new terminologies. But, this is very helpfull...